# OpenCv - cv::Exception at memory location C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to code an openCV program that opens a new widow that displays video from the webcam (laptop), and recieve  the error `Unhandled exception at 0x7530C41F in cv.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x001FF5D0.`

i have double checked all of the included dll's as well as the system path without any positive results.

here is my code:

```
#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include <opencv\highgui.h>
using namespace cv;
int main()
{

    Mat image;

    VideoCapture cap;
    cap.open(0);

    namedWindow("window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    while (1)
    {
        cap >> image;
        imshow("window", image);
        waitKey(33);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did your camera open when running this code?

Comment: most likely the `cap.open` fails, and then `cap >> image` crashes. you can set up an exception handler and inspect the exception message. but easiest here is probably just to single-step in the debugger.

Comment: @herohuyongtao , no the window did fully open, it got stuck in a load. also the webcam light did not turn on.., but my laptops default webcam viewer opened `dell webcam central` and it showed a single frame from the webcam, never more than one,

Answer (score 2):

I discovered the problem with my code, i had to put a hold on the execution of the program using `waitKey(1000)` or else the program will cause a memory leak. This must have been done because the connection to the webcam on my laptop was not fully established before executing the code. Putting a wait on the code execution prevents the crash and everything is now up and running.

```
  #include <opencv\cv.h>
    #include <opencv\highgui.h>
    using namespace cv;
    int main()
    {

        Mat image;

        VideoCapture cap;
        cap.open(0);

        namedWindow("window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
            waitKey(1000);

        while (1)
        {
            cap >> image;
            imshow("window", image);
            waitKey(33);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using [VideoCapture::isOpened()](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-isopened) would tell you if it's safe to use your VideoCapture instance?